# How to Analyze CSV entries between different rows in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, csv

Having the following CSV file

```
Number;Name;Description;Assessment;Result;Other_fields
101;Entity0001;Participant;Not_Qualified;;;

101;Entity0003;Participant;Qualified;10000;;

101;Entity0004;Participant;Qualified;8000;yes;

101;Entity0006;Participant;Qualified;12000,5;;

111;Entity0112;Participant;Qualified;100;;

111;Entity0113;Participant;Not_Qualified;120,5;;

111;Entity0110;Participant;Qualified;100;yes;
```

I want to analyze it like: within a same project, from above example project's "Number" can be equal to 101 or 111, what is
 - minimum "Result" among all of the Results / maximum Result; 
 - second to minimum Result; 
 - % difference between different "Results",
and so on. I am hopeful I will be able to add the calculations once and if I undestand the principle of how to compare entries accross rows.

Using standard Microsoft dev tool intended for use on CSV, entries in the lines(rows) can be parced as follows:

```
Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
            FileIO.TextFieldParser(
              "C:\Users\  ... path...  \test2.txt")
MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
MyReader.SetDelimiters(";")
Dim currentRow As String()

While Not MyReader.EndOfData
    Try
        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

        '### Columns of interest in txt (csv) file ####

        Dim NUMBER = currentRow(0)
        Dim RESULT = currentRow(4)

        '### Entries can be parced into variables 
        'from cvs lines and converted to numbers for math###

        Dim NUMBER_OF_LINE As Integer
        NUMBER_OF_LINE = CInt(MyReader.LineNumber)

        Dim NUMBER_CONVERTED As Integer

        Dim RESULT_CONVERTED As Decimal

        If RESULT <> "" Then
            If RESULT <> "Result" Then
                RESULT_CONVERTED = CDec(RESULT)
            End If
        End If

        If NUMBER <> "" Then
            If NUMBER <> "Number" Then
                NUMBER_CONVERTED = CInt(NUMBER)
            End If
        End If

        '### And then Written to File - omitted ###

Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
               "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
End while
```

This will work by separating the entries, in this example number of line (from MyReader.LineNumber), number of project (from "Number" in CSV) and results (from "Result" in CSV) are written to a file with "Number of line:", "Converted number:" "Converted result:" added to comment on those variables.

```
Number of line: 2 Converted number: 0 Converted result: 0 

Number of line: 3 Converted number: 101 Converted result: 0 

Number of line: 4 Converted number: 101 Converted result: 10000 

Number of line: 5 Converted number: 101 Converted result: 8000 

Number of line: 6 Converted number: 101 Converted result: 12000,5
```

'Output omitted

Could someone smarter please help: what kind of cycle (loop) I need, and how to implement it, to enable calculations (see above) of parts of entries, situated on separate lines/rows?

Comment: I dont understand how NUMBER plays into it, but it seems like you need to collect all the RESULT values so you can do the the math.  I guess those are Decimal or Double, so start by creating a List(Of T) to collect them all as you read the file

Comment: Does NUMBER act as a parition?  You want to calculate one set of results for 101 and another set for 100?  If so, you need to collect 2 sets of result values